# DRYer way to set column widths than with if statement?

Tags: templating, conditional

Craft `n00b` here. Really loving it so far, but am wondering if how I'm implementing this is the best option, or if maybe there's a more sophisticated solution.

Inside our content builder switch statement, I'd like to provide my client with the ability to build an image-and-text block wherein they can change the widths of the columns via a dropdown (`columnWidth`), which will then set the widths of the children. Here's what I have so far, but it seems a little inelegant, especially if I were to do more options or columns. Any pointers or is this the best way to handle this?

```
{% if content.columnWidth == "1-2" %}
  {% set columnOneWidth = "1-of-3" %}
  {% set columnTwoWidth = "2-of-3" %}
{% elseif content.columnWidth == "1-1" %}
  {% set columnOneWidth = "1-of-2" %}
  {% set columnTwoWidth = "1-of-2" %}
{% elseif content.columnWidth == "2-1" %}
  {% set columnOneWidth = "2-of-3" %}
  {% set columnTwoWidth = "1-of-3" %}
{% endif %}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-{{ content.columnOneWidth }}">
    [...]
  </div>
  <div class="column-{{ content.columnTwoWidth }}">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make it a bit more DRY and flexible is to use the `split` filter to create an array of column widths.

Also, you can save a bit of markup by calculating the total number of columns, and using a `for` loop to output the actual column DOM nodes:

```
{% set columns = content.columnWidth|default('1-2')|split('-') %}
{% set totalColumns = columns[0] + columns[1] %}

<div class="wrapper">
    {% for column in columns %}
        <div class="column-{{ column }}-of-{{ totalColumns }}">
           [...]
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MatsMikelRummelhoff - this is precisely the classy solution I was hoping for. Cheers!